# Why RegionMember does not return a useful result in this case?

Tags: bugs, regions, computational-geometry

**Bug persisting in 11.3**

---

I found `RegionMember` quite useful in retrieving the condition for which a point $(x,y)$ belongs to a region. Thus, this command works:

```
RegionMember[Disk[{0, 0}, 3, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/4}]][{x, y}]
```

$$(x|y)\in \mathbb{R}\land x^2+y^2\leq 9\land \frac{x}{3}\geq 0\land -\frac{y}{3 \sqrt{2}}\geq -\frac{x}{3 \sqrt{2}}$$

However, it does not for this self-intersecting polygon:

```
RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]][{x, y}]
```

MMA returns

```
{}[{x, y}]
```

or

```
RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}],{x, y}]
```

MMA returns the same:

```
RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}], {x, y}]
```

Anyone could explain why `RegionMember` fails in this case. The region seems to be not complicated.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. The documentation doesn't list any sort of restrictions, like self-intersections. Because it's not documented, then I would say it is not working as described. Particularly this: `RegionMember[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]`

Comment: If we apply `DiscretizeRegion` to the polygon, then we get a region that works with `RegionMember`.

Comment: @LouisB what you propose does not work for me (MMA ver. 11.2). Further, why the need of discretizing the polygon and not the disk?

Comment: I have just contacted support for assistance

Comment: Perhaps ``RegionMember[RegionUnion@@Rationalize[Graphics`PolygonUtils`SimplePolygonPartition[Polygon[{{0,0},{1,1},{0,1},{1,0}}]]],{x,y}]``.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the one-argument form returns an empty list is simply a bug.

For sufficiently complicated algorithm, it may be hard/impossible to return a useful answer.  This true even of self-intersecting polygons, though this particular one is admittedly not that complicated.  But then it should return unevaluated, rather than an empty list.